# Проверка на валидность записи

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, psql

Подскажите пожалуйста как мне проверить на валидность запись.
Есть таблица `name` в ней имена актеров, `person_info` хранит факты о актерах. Между собой связаны по name.id = person_info.person_id. Как проверить, что в таблице фактов об актерах нет ссылок на несуществующих актеров. Я думаю что там через full join, но даже приблизительно не знаю как это сделать. Поэтому код не прикладываю

Comment: *Между собой связаны по name.id = person_info.person_id.* Создайте соответствующий внешний ключ (FOREIGN KEY). Объявите зависимое поле как NOT NULL. И можете быть уверены, что ссылок в "никуда" - нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Как проверить, что в таблице фактов об актерах нет ссылок на несуществующих актеров.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM person_info 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM name
                   WHERE name.id = person_info.person_id )
```

вернёт все такие записи.

Если вернётся пустой набор - таких записей нет.

Answer (score 0):

> Как проверить, что в таблице фактов об актерах нет ссылок на
> несуществующих актеров.

Предлагаю использовать LEFT JOIN.
Следующий запрос выберет все записи и выведет список тех, у которых отсутствует name.id.

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM 
person_info AS pi 
LEFT JOIN name AS n ON pi.person_id = n.id 
WHERE n.id IS NULL
```